# Partition Theorem Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

given pdf fx(x) = $\frac{2x}{9}$ when 0<x<3 and its 0 otherwise and

pdf for y given x is

f<sub>Y|X</sub>(y|x) = $\frac{3y^2}{x^3}$ for 0<y<x

How do i find let's say P(Y<2)

I'm guessing i have to integrate as such

$$\int_{0} ^{3}P(Y<2|X=x)\frac{2x}{9}dx$$

But how do i find what P(Y<2|X=x) equals to for my integration? How do i go about doing this or generally just these type of questions?

Comment: [Probability theory](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_theory) is [about the measure-theoretic foundations](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8587/290189) of stochastics.  The tag ([tag:probability-theory]) should be used for questions concerning this subject, not for questions about calculating a specific probability.  Use ([tag:probability]) instead, see also [meta](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1686/290189).

Answer (score 1):

The joint density of $(X,Y)$ is the product of the conditional density of $Y$ given $X$ and the marginal density of $X$:
\begin{align}
f_{X,Y}(x,y) &= f_{Y\mid X=x}(y\mid x) f_X(x)\\
&= \left(\frac{3y^2}{x^3}\cdot \mathsf 1_{(0,x)}(y) \right)\left(\frac{2x}9\cdot \mathsf 1_{(0,3)}(x) \right)\\
&= \frac23\left(\frac yx\right)^2\cdot\mathsf 1_{(0,3)\times(0,x)}(x,y).
\end{align}
To find the marginal density of $Y$, we integrate the joint density over the range of $X$:
\begin{align}
f_Y(y) &= \int_{\mathbb R} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \int_y^3 \frac23\left(\frac yx\right)^2\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \frac29y(3-y),\quad 0<y<3.
\end{align}
It follows then that for $y\in(0,3)$ we have
\begin{align}
F_Y(y) &:= \mathbb P(Y\leqslant y)\\
&= \int_0^y f_Y(t)\ \mathsf dt\\
&= \int_0^y \frac29t(3-t)\ \mathsf dt\\
&= \frac{1}{27} (9-2 y) y^2.
\end{align}
When $y=2$, this quantity is $\frac{20}{27}$.